# Jqgrid - Mouseclick doesn't select rows

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

When I click in a row it is not selected, nothing happend....

This is my code, I think that scripts and CSS's are OK,

jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css

ui.jqgrid.css

jquery.min.js

jquery-ui.min.js

grid.locale-es.js

jquery.jqGrid.min.js

```
jQuery().ready(function (){

    jQuery("#resTables").jqGrid({
    url: "categorias.php?q=1",
    datatype: "xml",   
    colNames: ["ID", "Categorias Es", "Categorias En", "Categorias Ru"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "idCategoria", index:"idCategoria", key: true,width: 55 },
        { name: "nomCategoriaEs", index:"nomCategoriaEs", width: 250 },
        { name: "nomCategoriaEn", index:"nomCategoriaEn", width: 250, align: "right" },
        { name: "nomCategoriaRu", index:"nomCategoriaRu", width: 250, align: "right" },
    ],
    pager: jQuery("#paginacion"),
    rowList:[10,20,30],      
    sortname: "idCategoria",         
    sortorder: "desc", 
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,

    caption:"Categorias" });
    jQuery("#resTables").navGrid('#paginacion',{edit:true,add:true,del:false})
    jQuery("#resTables").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#paginacion");
    });
```

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code..

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
       // do some thing
}
```